# clojure/scala interop?

Tags: java, scala, clojure

I am attempting to interop to this simple scala code, but am having some troubles.

```
package indicators

class DoubleRingBuffer(val capacity:Int=1000) {
  var elements = new Array[Double](capacity);
  private var head=capacity-1
  private var max=0

  def size ():Int = {
    return max+1
  }

  def add(obj:Double):Double = {
    head-=1
    if (head<0) head=capacity-1
    return set(max+1,obj)
  }

  def set(i:Int,obj:Double):Double = {
    System.out.println("HI")
    if (i>=capacity || i<0)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(i+" out of bounds")
    if (i>=max) max=i
    var index = (head+i)%capacity
    var prev = elements(index)
    elements(index)=obj
    return prev
  }

  def get(i:Int=0):Double = {
    System.out.println("size is "+size())
    if (i>=size() || i<0)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(i+" out of bounds")
    var index = (head+i)%capacity
    return elements(index)
  }    
}
```

In clojure, i do this

```
(import 'indicators.DoubleRingBuffer)
(def b (DoubleRingBuffer. 100))
(pr (.size b)) ;;ERROR: No matching field found: size for class indicators.DoubleRingBuffer
(pr (.get b 33)) ;;returns 0: should throw an index out of bounds error!
(pr (.get b 100)) ;;throws index out of bounds error, as it should
```

In addition, i do not get any output to the console! Testing this code using scala works as expected. Whats going on here and how can i fix it so that clojure can use the scala code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these in REPL:

`(class b)` will probably tell you it's `indicators.DoubleRingBuffer`.

`(vec (.getDeclaredMethods (class b)))` will give you a vector of all methods declared in your class as if it was a Java class, so you can see their signatures.

Now, call your methods as seen in the signatures, with these method names and parameters.

<strike>I have a feeling the problem is in Scala's dealing with default value for method parameter.</strike>

EDIT: As OP described in a comment, it isn't.

If that doesn't work you can try to decompile your Scala bytecode to Java to find out how does `DoubleRingBuffer` class look like.

Comment: Thanks! Decompiling did the trick - java code was perfect, so in the end it was some weird bug with my incremental build tool - restarted and it worked as expected! btw, i used http://java.decompiler.free.fr/, great tool.

Comment: @josh: You can also try `scalac -print` which will print out a "desugared" version which is still Scala syntax, but isomorphic to Java, i.e. with all advanced Scala features removed. Also, there is `scalap` which works like `javap`, i.e. decompiles `.class` files.